# Find out another Skype user's IP address

Tags: skype

Skype has hidden user's IP by default so Skype resolvers are useless now. Can you still obtain person's IP if they are in your contacts list? Or is there no way to do that now?

Comment: Which version of Skype and on what OS?

Comment: Questions on SU are expected to [show some research effort](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) on your part and should be included in your question please.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the latest version of Skype, which should have done that a long time ago.

You can check their [blog post on the subject](http://blogs.skype.com/2016/01/21/to-our-gamers-ip-will-now-be-hidden-by-default-in-latest-update/):

> We have recently introduced the ability to hide a Skype user’s IP address and we’ve set this as a default status in the latest versions of Skype.
>
> Starting with this update to Skype and moving forward, your IP address will be kept hidden from Skype users. This measure will help prevent individuals from obtaining a Skype ID and resolving to an IP address.